# How to build regex to search for strings that has non-alphanumeric characters?

Tags: regex

I want a search for strings that has any special characters like alphanumeric characters. `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/` searches for strings that has no alphanumeric characters. But I don't want that. I want to filter with the only alphanumeric characters like `á`. So that it can match with `álgebra` but doesn't match with `algebra`. How can I build that?

Comment: You will need to define what _any special characters like alphanumeric characters_ you want. Theres a ton of them.

Comment: So, any string that **is not** everything `[a-zA-Z0-9]` should match? What about `#_~~`? should it match? Or ` ` (empty space) should match?

Comment: Try  `^(?=.*(?![A-Za-z])\p{L})[\p{L}0-9]+$`

Comment: Please provide more inputs and corresponding expected outputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to match alphanumeric strings that should contain any letter other than an ASCII letter.

You can use

```
^(?=.*(?![A-Za-z])\p{L})[\p{L}0-9]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VXDyAb/1/).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*(?![A-Za-z])\p{L})` - there  must be at least one letter that is not an ASCII letter
- `[\p{L}0-9]+` - one or more any Unicode letters or ASCII digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know what character will be taken. I think you could use `[list of characters]`.

I will give an example. I have some texts.

```
álgebara
algebara
algebrà
```

I use regex: `^.*?[áà].*?$`

Result:

```
álgebara
algebrà
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cku8E9/3)

**Details**:

- `^.*?[áà].*?$`: captures which string contains the specified character `á or à`